# Does reading an uninitialized malloc() memory invoke Undefined Behaviors?

Tags: c, malloc, undefined-behavior

I know this is a really basic question, and there may be a duplicate, but I couldn't find a strict answer to this specific question which refers to the Standard. (I saw some say it's UB, others say not)

If I allocate a block of memory without filling data into it,

```
int* ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

and then try to read it, the values there will be garbage.

But is this classified as an Undefined Behavior? Or is it just bad but at least not a UB?

Comment: "and then try to read it" --> as in `int`?  Confident the answer depends on how the data is read.  IIRC, `unsigned char` is least problematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Summary

The behavior of reading uninitialized memory provided by `malloc` is not undefined *per se*. It can result in undefined behavior if memory containing a trap representation is read with a non-character type, but this can occur only if the type has a trap representation. (Most modern C implementations do not have trap representations for integer types.)

However, while it is not fully undefined, neither is it fully defined. Attempting to read uninitialized memory is not required to actually read the memory.

### Details

C 2018 7.22.3.4 2 says, of the `malloc` function with parameter `size`:

> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose `size` is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

C 3.19.2 1 defines *indeterminate value* as:

> either an unspecified value or a trap representation

C 3.19.3 1 defines *unspecified value* as:

> valid value of the relevant type where this document imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance

Nothing in this makes the behavior undefined.

The behavior of reading a trap representation with a non-character type is not defined by the C standard, per 6.2.6.1 5. So, if the memory is read with a type that has a trap representation, and the resulting bits happen to contain values that represent a trap, then the behavior is undefined.

Trap representations in integer types are rare in modern C implementations. Many years ago, some systems would reserve certain bit patterns, such as the 16-bit 8000<sub>16</sub>, to represent uninitialized or invalid data, and attempting to use such a value in arithmetic would generate a trap. In a C implementation without trap representations in some type T, accessing uninitialized data through type T cannot encounter a trap representation. So the result must be an unspecified (and hence valid) value of the type.

Further, there is nothing else in the C standard that would make this behavior undefined. There is a rule in 6.3.2.1 2 that accessing an uninitialized object of automatic storage duration has undefined behavior if its address is not taken. However, the memory provided by `malloc` has allocated storage duration, not automatic. (That rule is an accommodation to certain Hewlett-Packard hardware with the capability of marking a register as uninitialized and trapping when it is used.)

Also, whole structures and unions are never trap representations, regardless of the types of their members. The most common trap representation in modern C implementations is a floating-point signaling NaN (Not a Number).

Note that the value in the allocated memory is unspecified, and the definition above states “this document imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance.” That means if you do this:

```
unsigned *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
printf("%u\n", *p);
printf("%u\n", *p);
```

the C standard imposes no requirement on which value is chosen for `*p` in the first `printf` and no requirement on which value is chosen in the second `printf`, **not even a requirement that they be the same as each other**. An “unspecified value” may act like it has bits that are changing by themselves from moment to moment. So, the behavior is not undefined—it cannot allow “anything” to happen to your program; your program cannot suddenly jump to a different function or wipe out other data—but neither is it defined to act like the memory has bits with fixed values.

This means you cannot reliably read the uninitialized memory—reads of the memory are not guaranteed to produce the bits that are actually in physical memory.

### Discussion

To see why the C standard allows the program to act like the bits in memory may be changing, consider this code:

```
unsigned a = *p + 3;
unsigned b = *p + 4;
```

For that code in normal situations, the compiler might generate assembly like this:

```
// As we start, registers r7, r8, and r9 already contain p,
// the address of a, and the address of b, respectively.
load  r3, (r7) // Get value of *p from memory.
add   r3, #3   // Add 3.
store r3, (r8) // Store sum to a.
load  r3, (r7) // Get value of *p from memory.
add   r3, #4   // Add 4.
store r3, (r9) // Store sum to b.
```

If the memory `p` points to happened to contain 0, then these instructions would store 3 in `a` and `4` in b. However, the rule that uninitialized memory is not required to behave as if it had a fixed value means the compiler’s optimizer is allowed to eliminate the load instructions. Hypothetically, that could result in instructions such as:

```
add   r3, #3   // Add 3.
store r3, (r8) // Store sum to a.
add   r3, #4   // Add 4.
store r3, (r9) // Store sum to b.
```

If `r3` happens to contain 0 when this code sequence starts, then 3 will be stored in `a`, and 7 will be stored in `b`. There is no possible value `*p` could have that would result in `*p + 3` being 3 and `*p + 4` being 7. So this code acts as if `*p` has changed by itself.

In practice, optimization would not just remove the load instructions here and not also recognize the subsequent instructions are also disconnected from fixed values and remove them. However, real-world optimizations get more complex than this. The license granted by the C standard allows the compiler to remove the parts of the code that it can figure out are not using defined values, even if it cannot figure out everything about the program.

Comment: That about covers every aspect. Nicely done. So in laymans terms uninitialized malloc'ed bytes are like a "Box of Chocolates -- you never know what you are going to get..."

Comment: Great answer!  It looks like in the editing, you may have changed some details.  In the example for `a = (*p + 3 ) * 4; b = (*p + 5) * 6`, the assembly seems to omit the multiplication and is computing `b = (*p + 4)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Yes, I started with more complicated code and reduced it while composing. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: The most useful way for an implementation treat uninitialized storage will depend upon the purposes for which it is being used.  Consequently, the Standard allows implementors that wish to serve their customers the option to treat such storage in whatever way those customers would find most useful, and as a consequence allows those that want to perform "clever" optimizations that break their customers' code without regard for whether such behavior would make their compiler more or less useful to their customers.

Comment: hold on, so what about J.2 which enumerates undefined behaviors, including "The value of the object allocated by the malloc function is used"?

Comment: @Cubbi: Annex J is informative (it is marked “(Informative)” in its title), not a normative part of the C standard. It contains summary information, omits some things, and has errors. Its contents are not a binding part of the standard. You can use it as a guide to help find things elsewhere in the standard, but you should use the normative parts for authoritative statements.

Comment: Interesting. looks like the definition of "undefined behavior" in section 3 used to include "use of ... indeterminately valued objects" in C99 (and the Rationale says that in an off-hand remark as well), but this doesn't appear anymore in C99:TC3.

Comment: I think a better example of why it could be advantageous to treat uninitialized storage as holding "wobbly" values would be in situations where a partially-initialized object is copied to two or more other locations.  If a compiler knows that some portions of the object have been initialized but some haven't, allowing it to skip copying the uninitialized portions in cases where doing so is convenient may offer performance benefits in cases where code wouldn't care about whether the portions of the copies corresponding to uninitialized portions of the object match each other.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Standard lacks any sort of meaningful vocabulary to describe situations where optimizations might yield a program behavior that observably differs from that implied by precise sequential program execution, but would nonetheless meet application requirements.  Instead, it seeks to characterize all situations where optimizations could observably affect program behavior using the catch-all phrase "Undefined Behavior", so as to uphold the misguided notion that optimizations must never affect the behavior of defined programs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read it.

The memory manager gave you the memory through your call to `malloc` so now it is yours and you can do anything you want with it. That includes reading it, e.g. printing it as an array of ints.

Eric discusses that the compiler may optimize away instructions, however, his discussion is based on the fact that the compiler knows about `malloc` and that it returns "uninitialized" memory, that is, memory that the user program did not assign a value to.

But in essence, `malloc` is just a function that returns an object and the compiler must assume the object returned has meaningful values, just as when a user function returns an object. Neither can there be "in-band" trap values as any value the memory has can be a legal value (all 32 bits of a 32 bit int are used). There can only be out-of-band trap values, that is, additional hardware like an extra hardware bit. But then trap values have become run-time.

Should the user have used `realloc` in which an existing block of memory (even a "no block" of memory) is expanded, then the compiler, even knowing about `realloc`, cannot assume anything about the returned object and cannot optimize instructions away. There is just nothing the compiler can assume.

Note that the memory manager may have set the memory to some unspecified value to prevent a program from reading data from the memory left by other uses, as a security measure.

Comment: No, you cannot reliably read it. Per my answer, the behavior is not undefined, but neither is it defined to actually read the memory.

Answer (score -1):

Because there are some situations where it may be useful for an implementation to guarantee that repeated reads of `malloc()` storage will yield consistent values unless or until it is written, but also some situations where it may be useful for an implementation not to be bound by such a guarantee, the question of whether any particular implementation should offer such a guarantee is a Quality of Implementation outside the Standard's jurisdiction.

As to whether a read of such storage may trigger side effects beyond yielding a meaningless value, that's not really clear.  Certainly it may be useful for a diagnostic implementation to trap on such reads, but the Standard doesn't explicitly provide for such things.  On the other hand, I don't think the Standard explicitly states that storage returned from `malloc` won't behave as though arbitrary objects have been written to it, thus causing such storage to be associated with arbitrary Effective Types.  Such questions again boil down to Quality of Implementation issues outside the Standard's jurisdiction.