# Copy array into array index C

Tags: arrays, c, memcpy

I want to copy an array into a second array at the position index.

What I did is:

```
uint8_t* _data = (uint8_t *)malloc(8U*1024);
uint32_t index= 4U;
uint8_t name[] ="TEST";
memcpy(&data[index], name, sizeof(uint32_t));
index+= 4U;
```

When I print data using:

```
    for (int j =0; j<index; j++)
    {
        printf("%c \n",data[j]);
    }
```

it is empty.
I want to find at data[3] "TEST"

Comment: The first 4 elements of `data` (or `_data`? Please [edit] and clarify) contain undetermined values, so what output do you expect?

Comment: Also using `sizeof(uint32_t)` doesn't make much sense here, you should rather use `sizeof(name)`.

Comment: Please fix a [mre]

Comment: `for (int j =0; j<offset; j++)` -> `for (int j = offset; j< offset + 4; j++)`

Comment: If you want to find what you copied, why are you reading from a different place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read from the same place you were writing to.

You want this:

```
  uint8_t* data = malloc(8U * 1024);    // remove the (uint8_t*) cast, it's useless
                                        // but it doesn't do any harm
  uint32_t index = 4U;
  uint8_t name[] = "TEST";
  memcpy(&data[index], name, sizeof(name));     // use sizeof(name)

  //  index += 4U;                                << delete this line

  for (int j = index; j < index + sizeof(name); j++)  // start at j = index 
  {                                                   // and use sizeof(name)
    printf("%c \n", data[j]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your data copied from index 4 but you print from index `0`. So how do you want to have it printed?

To visualize this problem:

```
int main() 
{
  uint8_t* data = malloc(8 * 1024); 
                                    
  size_t index = 4;
  uint8_t name[] = "TEST";
  memcpy(&data[index], name, sizeof(name));     

  for (size_t j = 0; j < index + sizeof(name); j++) 
  {                                                  
    printf("data[%zu] = 0x%02hhx (%c)\n", j, data[j], isalpha(data[j]) ? data[j] : ' ');
  }
}
```

and the output:

```
data[0] = 0x00 ( )
data[1] = 0x00 ( )
data[2] = 0x00 ( )
data[3] = 0x00 ( )
data[4] = 0x54 (T)
data[5] = 0x45 (E)
data[6] = 0x53 (S)
data[7] = 0x54 (T)
data[8] = 0x00 ( )
```

I hope it will help you understand the problem.

Also for indexes use the correct type `size_t` instead of `int` or `uint32_t`.

Comment: You should mention that the content of `data[0]` to `data[3]` is actually undetermined.

Comment: @Oka makes no difference in this case

Comment: @Oka because it is not an UB.

Comment: I suppose UB was the wrong term, but those [values are indeterminate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66840190/2505965).

Comment: @Oka And how does it affect the example if they are indeterminate? What is the danger? Will it make this program not working? Or it is just an unsuccessful pick attempt (related to wrong understanding of UB)?

Comment: The danger is confusion, mostly, if someone runs your example and gets a different result.

Comment: @Oka what confusion? There is no confusion. "TEST" will be always from byte no `4`. Other bytes around it do not matter. I think you simply do not understand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am going to do so that you can copy the name at the desired index. This one works because the length of the string that you are copying is 4 and sizeof(uint32_t) is 4. Otherwise you will need to input the length of the bytes you are copying.

```
memcpy((uint8_t*)&_data[index], &name, sizeof(uint32_t));
```