# C variable "0 initialisation" Linux (gcc) vs windows (MinGW)

Tags: c, linux, windows, initialization

On Arch linux using c i wrote a program to read in some data and calculate some statistical data.

When compiling on linux using gcc with no additional arguments just "gcc main.c", the output of the program is correct.

However compiling the program on windows using MinGW (again with no additonal arguments just "gcc main.c")causes the output to be incorrect, i figured out that it is incorrect because the inital value of a variable is not always 0 but either 0 or a really large positive or negative number. -- This variable is repeatedly added (x += a) to help calculate the standard deviation of the data.

The variable is the 2nd element in and array of type double (index 1).

This is the only variable that does this, it is never any other variable.
If I use the "-O2" flag then the error no longer occurs.

Is it always the case that variables are initialised to 0 on linux but not always on windows?
And if so, why is this the case?

Comment: If you don't initialize local variables, their values will be *indeterminate*. Consider them as garbage. If you want to use a variables value, always make sure it's initialized first. I'm ***guessing*** that's your problem, because you don't actually show any code.

Comment: *"Is it always the case that variables are initialised to 0 on linux."* No, it isn't but they might be. Only global and static variables are guaranteed to be initialised to `0` (once).

Comment: The rule is really, really simple - if you want a variable to be zero, just say so `= 0;`. It has no additional cost - in places where it would be zero anyway, nothing new happens - in all other places it saves your day.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it always the case that variables are initialised to 0 on linux*

Absolutely not.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void f( void ) {
   int i;
   i = 123;
}

void g( void ) {
   int j;
   printf( "%d\n", j );
}

int main( void ) {
   f();
   g();
}
```

```
$ gcc a.c -o a && ./a
123

$ uname
Linux
```

Automatic variables (i.e. variables declared in a function without the `static` keyword) are not initialized. If they appear to be zero, it's just by chance.

Had I enabled warnings (e.g. by adding `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`), the compiler would complain about this very issue with the program.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a
a.c: In function ‘f’:
a.c:4:8: warning: variable ‘i’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    4 |    int i;
      |        ^
a.c: In function ‘g’:
a.c:10:4: warning: ‘j’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   10 |    printf( "%d\n", j );
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

In C standard, automatic (non-static) variables are not initialized on declaration, they have the value previously present in the memory where they are stored, had before. This makes sense from a performance perspective, since putting to zero the memory will require an extra instruction, that doesn't make sense if that value isn't used later.

When you are passing `-O2` an optimization probably is somehow making that variable irrelevant, we cannot tell without knowing the code. But the bottom line is, always initialize your variables if the behaviour of the program depends on their initial value.

Comment: This applies to automatic variables, not to static ones, which are initialised to `0`.

Comment: Well, yes, @WeatherVane you're right, to variables that do not have some specific modifiers like `static`, I could emphasize that, thanks

Comment: A global variable does not need a specific modifier. A local variable does.

Comment: Well I don't tend to use global variables, less global variables that depend on them initialized to 0, I would also recommend explicitly initialize them just for the sake of clarity of intention in that case. Anyway, clarification made in the answer.

Comment: I can't agree with doing that. Global variables are automatically initialised to `0`. If you want clarity, add a code comment like `// initialised to 0`.

Comment: Ok, let's agree to disagree. For me, the comment is more verbose and adds no extra information or value, I use comments to express things not enough clear in code. But that's a matter of tastes.

Comment: Re “ they have the value previously present in the memory where they are stored, had before”: Uninitialized objects do not necessary have the value previously stored in the memory reserved for them. Students should not be told this because it cannot be relied upon when debugging, or for other purposes. See [“Discussion” in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66840190/298225).